# Uploading large file (10+ GB) from Web client via azure web site to azure blob storage

Tags: file-upload, azure-blob-storage

I've got a bit of a problem in uploading a really large file into azure blob storage.

- I have no problem uploading that file into the web site as a file
  upload in an upload directory.
- I have no problem either putting this into the blob storage, as chunking will be handled internally.

The problem I'm having is that the time it takes to move the large file from the upload directory to the blob storage takes longer than the browser timeout and the customer sees an error message.

As far as I know, the solution is to chunk-upload directly from the web browser.

But how do I deal with the block ids? Since the web service is supposed to be stateless, I don't think I can keep around a list of blocks already uploaded.

Also, can the blob storage deal with out-of-order blocks?

And do I have to deal with all the state manually?

Or is there an easier way, maybe just handing the blob service the httprequest input stream from the file upload post request (multipart form data)?

Lots of Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

You could move from the web server to blobs asynchronously. So return success for the original request back once file is on web server, and then have javascript query your web server periodically to confirm file has made it to durable storage in blobs. This javascript doing the polling can then display success to the user once it gets a success response from web server, confirming that the file has made it to blob storage.